# Good resource for Drag Coefficient vs Reynolds number (various shapes)?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations, drag, aerodynamics, turbulence

The Wikipedia page on [Drag Coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_coefficient) has a nice chart a little way down that shows the Drag Coefficient vs Reynolds number for a sphere, derived from experimental data. I am interested in looking at similar charts for other shapes and I have been searching online, but haven't been able to find much.

So, I am wondering if anyone is aware of a good resource that contains charts of Drag Coefficient vs Reynolds number for a variety of shapes. Examples of shapes I am interested in are: flat plate, cylinder, half-cylinder, rod with various sections (e.g. square, triangle). I would also be interested to see such charts for airfoils and internal flows through valves or piping.

The resource I am looking for would contain charts for a range of different shapes, over a similar range of Reynolds numbers to the chart on the Wikipedia page (i.e. covering the transition between laminar and turbulent flow, plus some distance either side).